# Dailybooth RSS Feed +Setting Image Size in RSS Feed

Tags: rss, blogs, sidebar

Is it possible for me to find an rss feed for a specific dailybooth users images? I'd like to implement my personal Dailybooth account into a blog sidebar. I'd also like the ability to set the image size and possible add a date to the image. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://dailybooth.com/rss/username/pictures.rss
```

?

Comment: How do I go about implementing it into the sidebar? Is it possible for me to set the image size? The RSS feed you provided (When I add my username in the place of "username") doesn't load.

Comment: I got that feed working but it's the dashboard feed. Not my personal images.

Comment: I have no clue about dailybooth - it's all google-fu here. http://maxbeatty.com/blog/2009/10/how-to-include-your-latest-dailybooth-com-photo-on-your-blog-or-website/ ?